# detect if an ASIHTTPReuquest is working

Tags: iphone

I hope detect an ASIHTTPRequest is working or not,
Thus I can cancel the async request of the ASIHttp.

Is there a way to detect if an ASIHTTPReuquest request is working?

Welcome any comment

Comment: You can debug your code and check that ASIHTTPRequest object should not nil. If yes then set two delegate methods, 1 for successfull and the other for failure. You can also follow this tutorial for further help about ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cancel all running async request with that code:

```
   for (ASIHTTPRequest *request in ASIHTTPRequest.sharedQueue.operations)
{
    [request cancel];
    [request setDelegate:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code it will definitely work:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Url"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",catId] forKey:@"categoryid"];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request startAsynchronous];
```